# Error: Expression must have a constant value in keil

Tags: c, keil

Here is my code:

```
int i; char *p;
char mnc[20],mcc[20],network_string[20];
char *array_parse[3] = {mnc ,mcc ,network_string}; /* Error occurs here */
WATCH_DOG_RESET;
      printf("\n\n##############Mobile Country Code############\r\n");
      Modem_Send("AT*PSHPLMN?\r\n",13);
      ModemWaitForAtResponse((char *)APN_Buffer,80,20);
        p = strtok (APN_Buffer,"'\":");
        while (p!= NULL)
        {
                    strcpy(array_parse[i++], p);
          //printf ("%s\r\n",p);
          p = strtok (NULL, "\":");
        }
        printf("%s\r\n",mnc);
        printf("%s\r\n",mcc);
        printf("%s\r\n",network_string);
```

This code works in code blocks but not in Keil uvision4.

I get "Expression must have a constant value".

Comment: "Expression must have a constant value"

Comment: Yes, I've used c99 mode. But hex file generated is not working in my micro controller.  However I've rectified the problem without using c99 mode just now. But curious about why this error occurs without c99 mode.

Comment: They are local variables. And the code is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you've somehow rectified your problem without compiling as C99. Prior to C99 (named because it was ratified in 1999), C89 (named because it was ratified in 1989) required that your kind of initialisation only use *constant expressions*.

Let us first explain that term, *constant expression*, since it is commonly confused with the `const` keyword. [C89/3.4 Constant expressions](http://www.bsb.me.uk/ansi-c/ansi-c#sec_3_4) does a far better job than I could at that, so without further adieu:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

In other words, if the compiler can work out the result without executing your code, it's a constant expression.

On the subject of initialisation, [C89/3.5.7](http://www.bsb.me.uk/ansi-c/ansi-c#sec_3_5_7) states:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration or in an initializer list for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be constant expressions.

Regarding aggregate types, within [C89/3.1.2.5](http://www.bsb.me.uk/ansi-c/ansi-c#sec_3_1_2_5), the following is stated

> Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

---

[C99/6.7.8 Initialization](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8) seems like it was an entire overhaul of that section, and the requirements for aggregate types (such as your array) were relaxed. Thus, compiling with a modern C99 or C11 compiler should certainly resolve your issue.

C11 didn't change too many things from C99. That standardisation mostly just added some small features like anonymous unions, threads and so on, deprecated `gets` and made VLA support optional... The section number describing initialization has changed; [in C11 it's section 6.7.9, instead](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9), which is likely because of the additions I mentioned beforehand.

---

Please read the standards with a little free time every now and then. Just twenty minutes a day. Do it next time you use a function that you use all the time, but which you've never read the manual for. Search for the function, see if it's in the standard so you can see if it's portable... learn about it, what it returns, etc. You never know what little nuances in C might turn your code from absolute garbage to brilliance, and you won't know the nuances unless you read about them.

Peace! Happy C99ing!

Comment: To be specfic, the relevant change in C99 was that initializers at block scope (i.e. inside a function) do not need to be constant expressions